Center of reduced von Neumann algebra
Consider the following fragment from the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido:

Later, there is the following claim:

Here, $z(e)$ is the central support of $e$, i.e. the smallest central projection $p$ in $\mathscr{M}$ such that $pe= e.$
In the above proof, I do not understand why we can assume that $z(e)=1$. I would be grateful if someone could explain. Thanks in advance!

$\def\m{\mathscr M}\def\z{\mathscr Z}$ Writing $z=z (e)$ to simplify notation,
$$\tag1
\m_e=e\m e=e(z\m z)e=(\m_z)_e.
$$
The central support of $e$ in $\m_z$ is the identity. So if you prove the equality for projections with central support the identity, then
$$
\z(\m_e)=\z((\m_z)_e)=(\z(\m_z))_e=(\z_z)_e=\z_e,
$$
where the first equality is due to $(1)$, the second equality is due to $e$ having central support the identity in $\m_z$, the third equality because $z$ is central, and the fourth because $e\leq z$.

Thanks. Extremely clear answer.

Glad I could help!
